# Why is my computer crashing?

Tags: crash

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7fa1bf9231): nvme: "Fatal error occurred. CSTS=0xffffffff US[1]=0x0 US[0]=0x81 VID=0x126f DID=0x2260
. FW Revision=C2.3.21\n"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IONVMeFamily/IONVMeFamily-470.100.17/IONVMeController.cpp:5320
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9238aabab0 : 0xffffff801e71a65d 
0xffffff9238aabb00 : 0xffffff801e854a75 
0xffffff9238aabb40 : 0xffffff801e8465fe 
0xffffff9238aabb90 : 0xffffff801e6c0a40 
0xffffff9238aabbb0 : 0xffffff801e719d27 
0xffffff9238aabcb0 : 0xffffff801e71a117 
0xffffff9238aabd00 : 0xffffff801eec1abc 
0xffffff9238aabd70 : 0xffffff7fa1bf9231 
0xffffff9238aabd90 : 0xffffff7fa1be4362 
0xffffff9238aabef0 : 0xffffff7fa1be4544 
0xffffff9238aabf30 : 0xffffff801ee95737 
0xffffff9238aabf70 : 0xffffff801ee954b2 
0xffffff9238aabfa0 : 0xffffff801e6c013e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily(2.1)[28183FA3-6A50-3611-BC20-A0717B657AAC]@0xffffff7fa1bd6000->0xffffff7fa1c18fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[5922E20B-D148-30DC-ABBA-0E99B3BE6940]@0xffffff7f9fb6e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[DF219CC1-366A-31FC-B8ED-17C584BA2549]@0xffffff7f9f249000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM(2.1)[D9C4809C-7B20-3663-A9C8-4DBC261AAD86]@0xffffff7f9fc9a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[3581A46A-F3F3-3CE7-BA52-7046E8D66C32]@0xffffff7f9f43e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[8F7948CF-5C25-33F4-A687-67F8A5B7906E]@0xffffff7f9f8ad000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19G2021

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Thu Jun 18 20:49:00 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D3A0F3D-D908-397B-BD16-8F48C0823A2E
Kernel slide:     0x000000001e400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801e600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801e500000
System model name: MacBookPro11,4 (Mac-06F11FD93F0323C5)
System shutdown begun: YES
Panic diags file available: NO (0xe00002cd)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 3279391375108
last loaded kext at 243223741076: @filesystems.exfat    1.4 (addr 0xffffff7fa2219000, size 65536)
last unloaded kext at 302360552010: >usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0 (addr 0xffffff7fa022a000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.0
com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs   288.2.14
net.telestream.driver.TelestreamAudio   1.1.1
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
com.shinywhitebox.iShowU-Audio-Capture  1.0.4
com.displaylink.driver.DisplayLinkDriver    2.5.1 (69398)
com.ScreamingBee.driver.SBVirtualMic64  1.1.0
@filesystems.exfat  1.4
@fileutil   20.036.15
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.6
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.6
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f7
>!ABacklight    180.3
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IHD5000Graphics 14.0.7
>eficheck   1
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!ALPC  3.1
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!A!IFramebufferAzul    14.0.7
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    7.0.6f7
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!UTopCaseDriver    3430.1
>!UCardReader   489.120.1
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
|IOAVB!F    850.1
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.6
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.3
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.6f7
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.6f7
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f7
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.6
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.6
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f7
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f7
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f7
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>!UAudio    323.4
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

This is a CPU thing? What remedies do I have? Thanks

Comment: what are you doing when it crashes?  You need to include this information along with the computer type and system version you are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message means that the operating system has stopped the computer from running because of an error within the NVM Express (NVMe) system. NVMe here refers to the SSD in your computer. It seems you do not have an original Apple SSD, but rather some third party SSD from OWC.

The cause of the error could either be a hardware error with the SSD, a software bug in the NVMe driver, or some compatibility issue between the two.

If this is the only time you have received the message, I would dismiss it as a random bug. If this is something that happens regularly for you, I would try booting from Recovery mode or from a separate, known good, macOS installations. If panics also occur there, it indicates a hardware issue - if it doesn't occur there (even when reading/writing to the drive), it could very well be a software issue - and a macOS reinstallation would probably be wise.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. I think the issue is that I was running out of disk space. I've cleared a lot of space out based on your answer here so hopefully that solves the issue, thanks!